# How to verify JWT with JWK - PHP

Tags: php, jwt, openid-connect, identity, public-key

I am working on Identity server and OpenId connect and since I need to do the implementation in a more dynamic manner and on multiple microservices in different languages, I am trying to understand the flow and doing the implementation with different stacks without depending on the client SDKs provided by the particular Identity server provider we are using. (in production, most likely, we will use some already built libs but my intention now is to grasp the concept of verification from ground up)

Now I am trying to simulate a case where we already have the access and id tokens and they are sent to a simple REST PHP function, and:

- **Do verification of JWT signature**
- Expiration check on the token
- Validation of Scope & Audience
- Pass username back to the frontend

*(not relevant but I generated the access_token with Authorisation code flow -> PKCE)*

This is my verification flow, I am using jose-php packages:

```
# public key
$components = array(
    'kty' => 'RSA',
    'e' => 'AQAB',
    'n' => 'x9vNhcvSrxjsegZAAo4OEuo...'
);


$public_key= JOSE_JWK::decode($components);



$jwt_string = 'eyJ...'; // Access_token
$jws = JOSE_JWT::decode($jwt_string);
$result = $jws->verify($public_key, 'RS256');
```

However, this returns undefined for $result. I am debugging other parts of the PHP script, and I will share my result with everyone here once I find a fix but I think there is a better way (not with provider exclusive client SDKs) to do this flow and there is a high chance that I am missing something.

**If anyone has a background with JWT token verification with PHP for identity server, It will be really great if you can share any better alternative or suggestions to do this here**

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps you can use a package like https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt

Comment: thank you for your message, I just checked the package and I can not see any validation against public key in the docs (maybe I passed quickly), does it cover JWK & JWS?

Comment: Hi again, I read the doc in details today and it supports the sign verification (sorry for the previous question) and seems even a bit easier to work with than jose-php. once my tests with jose-php are done I will try this lib as well, thank you again for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

#### This is an answer for anyone who seeks a simple verification middleware for jwks, might not be ideal for production!!! You are more than welcome to suggest a better solution :)

I switched to **firebase/php-jwt** as it is more convenient and straightforward to use and it was fairly easier to go quickly through its code and it does not return undefined anymore. Now the middleware code for validation looks like below:

```
$jwks = ['keys' => [[], []]; 

// JWK::parseKeySet($jwks) returns an associative array of **kid** to private

// key. Pass this as the second parameter to JWT::decode. 
// Instead of RS256 use your own algo
// $data can return error so wrap it in try catch and do as you desire afterward
$data= (array) JWT::decode("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", JWK::parseKeySet($jwks), ['RS256', 'RS256']);
```

For those who are willing to test a sample encoding and decoding process, feel free to use the private key and public key below: (Credit to firebase documentation with a bit of tweaking on my side to convert it to a simple Laravel controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

use \Firebase\JWT\JWK;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class JWTValidation extends Controller

{

    public function bundle(){

        

        $privateKey = <<<EOD

        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

        MIICXAIBAAKBgQC8kGa1pSjbSYZVebtTRBLxBz5H4i2p/llLCrEeQhta5kaQu/Rn

        vuER4W8oDH3+3iuIYW4VQAzyqFpwuzjkDI+17t5t0tyazyZ8JXw+KgXTxldMPEL9

        5+qVhgXvwtihXC1c5oGbRlEDvDF6Sa53rcFVsYJ4ehde/zUxo6UvS7UrBQIDAQAB

        AoGAb/MXV46XxCFRxNuB8LyAtmLDgi/xRnTAlMHjSACddwkyKem8//8eZtw9fzxz

        bWZ/1/doQOuHBGYZU8aDzzj59FZ78dyzNFoF91hbvZKkg+6wGyd/LrGVEB+Xre0J

        Nil0GReM2AHDNZUYRv+HYJPIOrB0CRczLQsgFJ8K6aAD6F0CQQDzbpjYdx10qgK1

        cP59UHiHjPZYC0loEsk7s+hUmT3QHerAQJMZWC11Qrn2N+ybwwNblDKv+s5qgMQ5

        5tNoQ9IfAkEAxkyffU6ythpg/H0Ixe1I2rd0GbF05biIzO/i77Det3n4YsJVlDck

        ZkcvY3SK2iRIL4c9yY6hlIhs+K9wXTtGWwJBAO9Dskl48mO7woPR9uD22jDpNSwe

        k90OMepTjzSvlhjbfuPN1IdhqvSJTDychRwn1kIJ7LQZgQ8fVz9OCFZ/6qMCQGOb

        qaGwHmUK6xzpUbbacnYrIM6nLSkXgOAwv7XXCojvY614ILTK3iXiLBOxPu5Eu13k

        eUz9sHyD6vkgZzjtxXECQAkp4Xerf5TGfQXGXhxIX52yH+N2LtujCdkQZjXAsGdm

        B2zNzvrlgRmgBrklMTrMYgm1NPcW+bRLGcwgW2PTvNM=

        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

        EOD;

        $publicKey = <<<EOD

        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

        MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8kGa1pSjbSYZVebtTRBLxBz5H

        4i2p/llLCrEeQhta5kaQu/RnvuER4W8oDH3+3iuIYW4VQAzyqFpwuzjkDI+17t5t

        0tyazyZ8JXw+KgXTxldMPEL95+qVhgXvwtihXC1c5oGbRlEDvDF6Sa53rcFVsYJ4

        ehde/zUxo6UvS7UrBQIDAQAB

        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

        EOD;

        

        $payload = array(

            "iss" => "example.org",

            "aud" => "example.com",

            "iat" => 1356999524,

            "nbf" => 1357000000

        );

        

        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');

        //echo "Encode:\n" . print_r($jwt, true) . "\n";

        

        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $publicKey, array('RS256'));

        

        /*

         NOTE: This will now be an object instead of an associative array. To get

         an associative array, you will need to cast it as such:

        */

        

        $decoded_array = (array) $decoded;

        return response()->json(['jwt' => $jwt, 'decoded' => $decoded]);

        //echo "Decode:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "\n";

    }
}
```

**Now back to my first question again :)**

In case that I validate the key with the help of this library as the first piece of the code, am I exposing any vulnerability? or will it be a time-consuming task in long run to maintain a custom verification flow like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same process right now :).

The biggest downside now is that I have to decode the JWT first to extract the iss endpoint, then call the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint, extra the correct key from there and validate the JWT again with the correct key information.

I'm doing it manually now, because I'm not aware of any libraries that support this.

Comment: I ended up using socialite and making a local version https://github.com/rinkp/socialite-azureb2c repo and tweaking it a little bit and updating it to PHP 8 for azureb2c with Authorization code flow (not PKCE though)